# NSPredicate comparing keys where one may be nil

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass `Foo` which has two modelled properties: `a` and `b`.

`a` and `b` are `NSString`s, but there's no guarantee they will be instantiated -- they could just as well be `nil`. In fact, as it happens right now, all `Foo` instances have `b` equal to `nil`.

I want to fetch all `Foo` objects such that `a != b`:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Foo"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a != b"];    
NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

The resulting array is empty, even though I have cases where I know for a **fact** that I have 10 objects where `a` is definitely **not** `nil`.

In fact, I can even prove that by adjusting my predicate to:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a != nil"];
```

Which works fine, and returns to me the 10 objects.

This behaviour of `NSPredicate`/`NSFetchRequest` is just plain weird and I can't figure out why it returns an empty result for the original `a != b` predicate where `b` is `null`. But works fine when I change it to `a != nil` (which is just the hard-coded value of `b` anyway!!)

Having written some more test code to explore this issue, it seems that when comparing keys, if either the LHS or RHS of the `==` property is `nil`, then the resulting array is empty.

On the other hand if the LHS and RHS are both non-`nil`, then it seems to work fine.

What am I missing here? Why does the `==` operator fail when comparing two keys where one or both of them are `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nil` values are store as `NULL` in the SQLite database, and SQLite treats `NULL` as the
"undefined value". The predicate "a != b" is translated to the SQLite query

```
SELECT ... FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZA <> t0.ZB
```

and that does not return any rows where `t0.ZA` or `t0.ZB` is NULL (aka "undefined").
Therefore, `a != b` does not return any objects where `a` or `b` is `nil`.

For the same reason, the predicate `a == b` does not return objects where both `a`
and `b` are `nil`.

On the other hand, the predicate `a != nil` is translated slightly differently to

```
SELECT ... FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE   t0.ZA IS NOT NULL
```

using "IS NOT" instead of "<>". Therefore this query really returns all objects with
`a != nil` (as one would expect).

I don't know if this behaviour is explicitly documented in the Core Data documentation
(I haven't searched yet), but this is how SQLite treats NULL values and it should explain
the behaviour that you observed.

You can see the SQLite statements if you add the launch argument

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3
```

for the executable in the Scheme editor.

**UPDATE:** From ["Attributes"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW6) in the "Core Data Programming Guide":

> You can specify that an attribute is optional—that is, it is not
>   required to have a value. In general, however, you are discouraged
>   from doing so—especially for numeric values (typically you can get
>   better results using a mandatory attribute with a default value—in the
>   model—of 0). The reason for this is that SQL has special comparison
>   behavior for NULL that is unlike Objective-C's nil. NULL in a database
>   is not the same as 0, and searches for 0 will not match columns with
>   NULL.

This does at least mention that optional attributes are special and may not
behave as expected.

The ["Predicate Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html) has also a section about NULL values and testing for NULL.

Comment: Understood! Thank you for a very clear explanation. I couldn't find any reference to this in Core Data documentation. So aside from rewriting my predicate as `(a == nil AND b != nil) OR (a != nil AND b == nil) OR (a != b)` is there any short-hand for this?

Comment: @jon: I could not find a shorter version.